# How to format a numeric value in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I have a set of code that generates a number which can be seen below

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT ("node_id",3)::numeric) + 1 as newnum from sewers.structures
    WHERE(
    ST_WITHIN(
        ST_CENTROID((ST_SetSRID(structures.geom, 4326))), 
        ST_SetSRID((SELECT geom FROM sewers."Qrtr_Qrtr_Sections" WHERE "plat_page" = '510A'),4326)) ) and "node_id" != 'PRIVATE' and "node_id" !='PRIV_SAN' and "node_id" !='PRIV_STORM'
```

When I run this it generates a number based on the previously placed values. The out put will be a number that can be up to 3 digits. I want to take an output of less than three digits, and force it into a 3 digit format.

For example, if I generate the number `93` I would like to format it as `093`. Same for single digit numbers like `2`, I want it to be formated at `002` and so on. However, if it generates a 3 digit number, I want it to keep the same format, so `121` stays as `121`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, you're looking for `lpad()`:

```
WITH j (x) AS (
  VALUES (2),(121),(93)
)
SELECT lpad(x::text,3,'0') FROM j;

 lpad 
------
 002
 121
 093
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the output will be a string, you can use `to_char` with a format of three `0`

```sql
select to_char(1,'000');
 to_char
---------
  001
(1 row)
```